# Testing if first character of a string is non-numeric in LibreOffice Basic

Tags: string, vba, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I have column of strings mostly composed of numbers. Most of these strings are indeed 10 digit numbers formatted as string like :`1234567890` except a few of them. Those exceptions start with a literal character with a letter to be specific like :`A1234567890`. What I want to do is while looping over that column I want to check on first characters and if it is a literal I want to branch my code. I'm not familiar with LibreOffice Basic yet VBA so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about Microsoft Office?  If not, then please remove the `vba` tag and do not mention VBA in the question.

Comment: LibreOffice Basic is similar to `VBA` in large portion. I don't think putting a `VBA` tag to this question violates any rule but to reach more people who can actually have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing `6.14. Display all data in a column` in [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php)  shows how to loop through all cells in a column.

To find out if the cell's string is numeric, use the [IsNumeric](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/IsNumeric_Function_Runtime) function:

```vb
If IsNumeric(aCell.String) Then
```